# Set Focus on Controls in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have repeater control with textboxes and dropdown controls for searching.While user search any content in any textbox the page is postbacked to load the repeater with search criteria.At this time i need to set focus on the particular control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer for my question and i am posting it.

```
  if(!postback){//code here}
  else
  {
    Control cont = this.Page.FindControl(Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]);
    if (cont != null)
        cont.Focus();
  }
```

this helps to set focus on controls if we don't know the id of the target controls

Answer (score 2):

try this code .
    TextBox.Focus();

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178232.aspx

Comment: Ridiculous!!!  I know textbox.focus() will set the focus.My problem is i have two or more text controls and i can't predict which textbox the user clicked to search

Comment: @Satheesh, You should add more tags or be more specific than c# (like asp.net, mvc.net etc) to avoid answers like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to achieve this functionality .This works for a particular control only

`<body onload="setFocus()">`

```
function setFocus()
{
    document.'your_control_id'.focus();
}
```

For more info see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can set focus to any control by setting **ControlName.Focus()**. If, due to any reason, the focus shifts to any other control after load, you can try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Load += new EventHandler(Loaded);
}

private void Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dropDownList.Focus();
}
```